# How to avoid being charged for Apples CloudKit?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I wanna use CloudKit for a new App of mine which will be free (0$). That's why it would be bad if my app would reach the free tier limit of Apples Cloud Kit plans and to occasion costs.

I read some posts, the official Apple developer documentation, etc. I did not find a way how to prevent it by rule or by an `code-sided` check to use more quota as the free tier would provided.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: That is correct. I'll delete this question. Could you please help to to find a better 'place'  for my question? It is meta-code-related.

Comment: I'm not sure; I guess the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: I think it is a good question; with a subject/link to iCloud programming that is close to everyone working in this domain^s heart!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, you will not be charged automatically if you exceed the free CloudKit transfer/storage limits. Instead, the CloudKit response will be an error. For example, if too many clients send requests at the same time, some of them will receive a `CKErrorLimitExceeded`. If you look at the [CloudKit Error Codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckerrorcode), you will find similar codes for exceeded storage quota.